# Qt4 and GLew seem to be incompatible with each other

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4, glew

I'm trying to move from GLee to glew, because GLee doesn't work under VC2010 and hasn't been updated in a while. I'm having trouble with the header files, because the both libs want their header file defined first. glew doesn't like gl.h being defined first (which is defined in QtOpenGL), and QtOpenGL specifically states that glew should be defined after QtOpenGL.

Searching shows many people using both glew and Qt together just fine. At the very least, I'd like a definitive answer about the compatibility. I've added the .h and .c files to my project, because in future I won't have to mess around installing .lib and .dll files.

Here's the code in QtOpenGL that gets called if glew is included first:

```
#ifdef __GLEW_H__
#warning qglfunctions.h is not compatible with GLEW, GLEW defines will be undefined
#warning To use GLEW with Qt, do not include <QtOpenGL> or <QGLFunctions> after glew.h
#endif
```

And here's the code called if QtOpenGL is included first:

```
#if defined(__gl_h_) || defined(__GL_H__) || defined(__X_GL_H)
#error gl.h included before glew.h
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLEW and qtfunctions all define the same things. You can't use them together, and you shouldn't want to. All you're using Qt for is to initialize the OpenGL context. So don't include qtfunctions. Try to include just QGLWidget and the stuff that class needs.

Comment: I want to use shader programs and buffer objects which aren't defined in QtOpenGL (but which is required to create a OGL rendering window). And without GLEW, I'm stuck with the ancient version of OpenGL in Microsoft's headers.

Comment: @usm: I explained how to do that: stop including qtfunctions. Include GLEW first, then just include the minimal stuff you need to create a QGLWidget instance. Oh, and nobody's forcing you to use Qt; if you don't like it, there are many other cross-platform ways to create an OpenGL window.

Comment: My apologies. In my frustration I misinterpreted your answer to mean that qtfunctions is also used for accessing pointers to newer GL functions, just like GLEW. Also, I didn't know that QtOpenGL is actually a composite of several other header files, so your suggestion went over my head. I took a break, and with a clear mind had another go at it. There were issues with missing Qt dlls in the precompiled version of Qt for vc2010, but with some work (manually building Qt) I finally got it working. Thanks for all your help!